# Using a python string output in curl

Tags: python, string, curl, output

I have this python script

```
users=['mark','john','steve']

text=''

for user in users:
    text+=str(user + " ")

print(text)
```

I want to output that string "text" into a curl terminal command.

I tried:

```
curl -d "@python-scirpt.py" --insecure -i -X POST https://10.10.10.6/hooks/84kk9emcdigz8xta1bykiymn5e
```

and

```
curl --insecure -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"text": 'python /home/scripts/python-script.py'}' https://10.10.10.6/hooks/84kk9emcdigz8xta1bykiymn5e
```

or without the quotations in the text option

Everything returns this error

```
{"id":"Unable to parse incoming data","message":"Unable to parse incoming data","detailed_error":"","request_id":"fpnmfds8zifziyc85oe5eyf3pa","status_code":400}
```

How to approach this ? Any help is appreciated thank you.

another approach would be to curl inside python but would need help in that too. 
Thank you

Comment: Python have `requests` module to make HTTP requests.

Comment: In the python script, instead of running all that you can just do `' '.join(users)` for creating the string out of the list

Comment: Thank you @MartínGómez I am very new to python so had no knowledge of this yet, very helpful.

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM would you care to guide a bit through it or reference a link or anything

Comment: The `requests` [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) are a very good resource

Answer (score 1):

Use command substitution (i.e. `$(...)`) to make the shell run the python code first.

So

```
curl -d "$(python-scirpt.py)" --insecure -i -X POST https://10.10.10.6/hooks/84kk9emcdigz8xta1bykiymn5e
```

Comment: /home/scripts/python-script.py: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `
('
/home/scripts/python-script.py: line 12: `text=' '.join(users)'
curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name 'chat2.temple.lan' does not match target host name '10.10.10.6'

weird that it says chat2.temple.lan because it is chat.temple.lan

Comment: The first error is to do with your Python script. Run that on its own until you get it working.

Second error is probably because you're trying to use https for an IP address, but the site seems to have a cert only linked to its domain name (i.e. chat2.temple.lan). If it's on a local trusted network you can use http instead.

Comment: Also when I run this for instance
curl --insecure -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"text": "Testing"}' https://10.10.10.6/hooks/84kk9emcdigz8xta1bykiymn5e
It works

Comment: If you're sending data as JSON you should probably use `json.dumps` to ensure it's formatted correctly, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html